# CRUD-Repository OrderBy does not expect parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have this method defined in a `CRUD-Repository` :

```
List<MenuPriceByDay> findAllOrderByUpdateDate();
```

but when I init the app. I got this error:

> Failed to create query for method public abstract java.util.List
>   com.tdk.backend.persistence.repositories.MenuPriceByDayRepository.findAllOrderByUpdateDate()!
>   No parameter available for part updateDate SIMPLE_PROPERTY (1): [Is,
>   Equals] NEVER.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please can you check this [spring jpa documentation ?](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)

It must be like that

```
// Enabling static ORDER BY for a query
List<Person> findByLastnameOrderByFirstnameAsc(String lastname);
List<Person> findByLastnameOrderByFirstnameDesc(String lastname);
```

> You can apply static ordering by appending an OrderBy clause to the
>   query method that references a property and by providing a sorting
>   direction (Asc or Desc).